# How insert CMS static block Top Menu Magento 2.x?

Tags: magento2, phtml

I create CMS static block  Identifier :`header_menu_top`

**app/design/frontend/Vendor/themeXXX/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

```
  <referenceBlock name="header.panel">
  <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="header_menu_top">
     <arguments>
         <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">header_menu_top</argument>
     </arguments>
  </block>
  </referenceBlock>
```

But Can not display to top header , Actuality i want to show below

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/MyTheme/Vendor_MyTheme/templates/html/header.phtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last i got solution to call phtml page .

**app/design/frontend/Vendor/MyTheme/Vendor_MyTheme/templates/html/header.phtml**

```
  <?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('header_menu_top')->toHtml();?>
```